# How to add an entire list of string with all elements to a class in C# Form Application

Tags: c#, list

I have an *Employee* **Class** with different values, that I call from my *Main* **Form**, and I want to add a *list* element to my **class**, but it doesn't work as I want it to work.

My Employee Class looks like this:

```
    public class Employee
{
    public Employee(int id, string name, string mobil, string email,
        List<string> listAttributes) 
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Mobil = mobil;
        Email = email;
        ListAttributes = listAttributes;
    }
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string Mobil { set; get; }
    public string Email { set; get; }
    public List<string> ListAttributes { set; get; }
}
```

On my main form I have a list of employee like this:

```
    public List<Employee> WorkerDatas = new List<Employee>();
```

And a list like this for the attributes:

```
    public List<string> Attributes = new List<string>();
```

And I add new emloyee datas into this list with an "Add Employee Button". The button's On_Click event is like this:

```
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WorkerDatas.Add(new Employee(EmployeeIndex, txbName.Text, txbMobil.Text, txbEmail.Text, Attributes));
    }
```

Everything works fine as I want (the Id, name, mobile, email), but the list (Attributes) doesn't work properly.
If I add 1 employee, it looks like its working, but when i add a second one, my first employee has the same attributes as my second. (I choose attributes from a CheckedListBox, there are 7 attributes that my employees may or may not have.)

I hope that I was clear, I could not find similar problem with solutions, so I had to ask. Thank you for any help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my psychic debugging powers are telling me that you're passing the same list into each `Employee` Constructor, `List<T>` is a reference type, which means that the variable that holds is only holds a pointer to the real list.

A consequence of that is that every Employee, has the exact same list, and when you change, it, you change it for all employees.

You should construct a brand new list of Attributes to pass into each Employee.

since, `string` is immutable and behaves mostly the same as a value type does, you only have to worry about the list itself.  adding a `ToList()` should do the trick.  `ToList()` always returns a new list.

```
WorkerDatas.Add(new Employee(EmployeeIndex, txbName.Text, txbMobil.Text, txbEmail.Text, Attributes.ToList()));
```

Note, if `Attributes` was a list of some other non-immutable reference type, you'd have to make copies of the elements too.

Comment: Agreeing here because we are missing a big piece which is the logic behind Attributes and how it is initializing the CheckedItems.